# What is the meaning of 大家纷纷 in 大家纷纷出主意?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

这样的行为必须一再地重复，为此，比赛不得不断断续续地进行，缺少了激烈紧张的气氛，连运动员都不满意，更何况看比赛的球迷呢？为了解决这个问题，大家纷纷出主意，想出了很多取球的办法。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 13.

What is the meaning of 大家纷纷? Everyone in great numbers or experts in great numbers? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

纷纷 - 一个接一个地; 接二连三地; 多而杂乱

大家纷纷出主意 - Everybody one after the other offers ideas.